# Retrieving images from directory stored with sequential names and storing in array

Tags: php, image, video, ffmpeg

Using ffmpeg I have generated a sequence of images from the video, which are stored in the directory with a sequential names, Example: for video one.mp4, the sequence is

```
onethumb0001.jpg,onethumb0002.jpg,onethumb0003.jpg,onethumb0004.jpg,onethumb0005.jpg,onethumb0006.jpg,onethumb0007.jpg,onethumb0008.jpg,onethumb0009.jpg,onethumb0010.jpg,onethumb0011.jpg,onethumb0012.jpg...onethumb0100.jpg....onethumbnnnn.jpg
```

Similarly for two.mp4,

```
twothumb0001.jpg,twothumb0002.jpg,twothumb0003.jpg,twothumb0004.jpg,twothumb0005.jpg,twothumb0006.jpg,twothumb0007.jpg,twothumb0008.jpg,twothumb0009.jpg,twothumb0010.jpg,twothumb0011.jpg,twothumb0012.jpg...twothumb0100.jpg....twothumbmmmm.jpg
```

All the images for both one.mp4 and two.mp4 and any n.mp4 are stored in the same directory.

When one.mp4 is selected for preview. I want to grab all the images only of one.mp4 and stored them in sequence in the php array, as follows,

```
$a = ["onethumb0001.jpg","onethumb0002.jpg","onethumb0003.jpg","onethumb0004.jpg","onethumb0005.jpg","onethumb0006.jpg","onethumb0007.jpg","onethumb0008.jpg","onethumb0009.jpg","onethumb0010.jpg","onethumb0011.jpg","onethumb0012.jpg"..."onethumb0100.jpg"...."onethumbnnnn.jpg"];
```

Note: the number of images available for different videos is different and unknown in advance to read from directory.

Please guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`glob`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) to search for the matching files. For example

```
$video = 'one.mp4';
$filenum = basename($video, '.mp4');
$videodir = '/home/some/path/';
$thumbs = glob("{$videodir}{$filenum}thumb*.jpg");
$thumbs = array_map('basename', $thumbs);
print_r($thumbs);
```